# How can I use Z3 SMT locally

Tags: z3, z3py

Any one have an idea how to use Z3 SMT locally instead of using the website?
I know how to use z3.py but I need to use SMT. rise4fun.com is down which makes it difficult to check my models.

Answer (score 0):

Z3 binaries for various platforms are available for download on the [Z3 Website](http://z3.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks Chris for your answer.